# Customizing google plus url default comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-plus, social-networking

Is it possible to add a comment by default when using google plus share link?
The url is the following

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en&url=URL_TO_SHARE
```

I've trieid adding &message=MESSAGE but that didn't help. Also tried &comment and &text

Comment: I very much doubt it since it is an unofficial method of sharing that is supposed to popup form a +1 button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to warn you, this is not an officially supported part of the Google+ platform. I strongly recommend that you use the [+1 button](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/) to share content to Google+.

That being said, there is no paramater that you can set to specify the message. The closest you can get to this is to use schema.org, open graph or HTML meta elements to specify the description of your target URL just like the [+Snippet](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#plus-snippet) for the +1 button.

Comment: You're correct. Meta elements work too. I've amended my answer. :)